# Printing the required number of inverted star patterns

Tags: lua

An inverted star pattern consists of a given number of rows of asterisks; in which each next row has one asterisk fewer, until one asterisk in the last row remains; with every fifth asterisk replaced with a `#` (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOsdt.png)):

```
****#*
****#
****
***
**
*
```

User is prompted to enter the number of star patterns and then, for each pattern, its width, which is the same as height. Then the required number of patterns of needed size, is to be output.

Comment: Please explain the part "without using variable as limit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, until the part "without using variable as limit" is clarified, it's

```lua
-- Localise functions that are called several times, for performance.
local floor = math.floor
local len, sub, rep = string.len, string.sub, string.rep
local insert, concat = table.insert, table.concat

local function pattern (size, template)
    -- Repeat template as many times as necessary to cover size and cut off what is not needed:
    local line = sub (rep (template, floor (size / len (template) ) + 1 ), 1, size)
    local lines = {}
    while (len (line) > 0) do
        insert (lines, line)
        line = sub (line, 1, -2)        -- cut the last character off.
    end
    return concat(lines, '\n')
end

io.write ('How many inverted star patterns do you want? ')
local no = tonumber (io.read ()) or 0
local patterns = {}

for i = 1, no do
    io.write ('How many rows in pattern no. ' .. tostring (i) .. '? ')
    patterns[i] = pattern (tonumber (io.read ()) or 0, '****#')
end

print (concat (patterns, '\n'))
```

Note that rows of the star pattern and the patterns themselves are stored as tables that are concatenated with `table.concat` only when they are complete, rather than as strings appended on any iteration using `..`. This is faster, since in Lua a string will be re-allocated on each concatenation.

And this is an alternative implementation of the `pattern` function:

```lua
local function pattern (size, template)
    local length = len (template)
    local rows = {}
    for i = size, 1, -1 do
        -- Repeat template as many times as necessary to cover i and cut off what is not needed:
        insert (rows, sub (rep (template, floor (i / length) + 1), 1, i))
    end
    return concat (rows, '\n')
end
```

And this is another implementation, where pattern rows are cached, which might speed the program up:

```lua
local cache = {}
local function pattern (size, template)
    local length = len (template)
    local rows = {}
    for i = size, 1, -1 do
        -- Repeat template as many times as necessary to cover i and cut off what is not needed.
        -- And cache it.
        cache[i] = cache[i] or sub (rep (template, floor (i / length) + 1), 1, i)
        insert (rows, cache[i])
    end
    return concat (rows, '\n')
end
```

Comment: Well, According to program we have ask user how many star pattern he/she wanted to make after it we ask for rows of first pattern and  after it rows of second(According to no. of pattern) when he/she enter 2 14 5 then answer should be like in picture which I attached in que. Actually, I'm new for Lua so, help me get out of it...

Comment: @Dev Soni, see the updated question and answer.

Comment: Really, Really Thanks you