# How to print a pattern of stars and hash such that there should be a hash after four stars in lua programming

Tags: lua

The pattern should be in this way:

```
****#****#****
****#****#****
```

I tried in this way:

```
-- generatePattern function to print the pattern of start(*) and hash(#)
function generatePattern()
    --n = tonumber(io.read())
    for i=14, 1, -1 do
        for j=1, i, 1 do
            io.write("*")
            if (i==5) then
                char = "*"
                newchar=char.gsub(string,"#")
                print("#")
            end
        end
        print("  ")
    end
end

-- read the test cases input
tc = tonumber(io.read())

-- for each case, call the generatePattern function to print the pattern
for i=1,1 do
    generatePattern()
end
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64259674/6632736.

Comment: could you explain what your code should do? because I have no idea how you came up with something like this to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what your code does

```
-- define a function generatePattern
function generatePattern()

    -- loop 14 times, reducing i = 14 by 1 each turn
    for i=14, 1, -1 do
        -- loop i times
        for j=1, i, 1 do
            -- output a star
            io.write("*")
            -- if i == 5 (this happens exactly once!)
            if (i==5) then
                -- create a global variable char that stores a string "*"
                char = "*"
                -- cause a lua error for using the string libraries table as a literal string
-- looks like you tried to replace something with a hash
                newchar=char.gsub(string,"#")
                -- print a hash
                print("#")
            end
        end
        print("  ")
    end
end

-- read a value you don't use
tc = tonumber(io.read())

-- call your function in a loop
for i=1,1 do
    generatePattern()
end
```

I have no idea how you came up with this logic. Please use pen an paper and write down what needs to be done to achieve your goal.

You certainly don't want to print 14 asterisks, then 13 asterisks, all the way down to 5 asterisks where you print a single hash. This is complete non-sense (no offense!)

So what do we need to do? We want to print `"****#****#****"`

The trivial way is obviously `print("****#****#****")`

Creating a function to generate this string only makes sense if there are any parameters that would change that string. Like a number of hashes so you can easily print `"****#****"` and `"****#****#****#****"` and others.

So why not simply take the number of hashes as input.

```
function generatePattern(numHashes)
  numHashes = numHashes or 0
  local output = ""
  local numCharacters = numHashes + 4 + numHashes * 4
  for i = 1, numCharacters do
    -- append a # if i is a multiple of 5, append a * else
    output = output .. (i % 5 == 0 and "#" or "*")
  end
  return output
end

-- test 
for i = 0, 5 do
  print(generatePattern(i))
end
```

prints:

```
****
****#****
****#****#****
****#****#****#****
****#****#****#****#****
****#****#****#****#****#****
```

And if you want to make the number of asterisks adjustable as well do this:

```
function generatePattern(numHashes, numAsterisks)
  numHashes = numHashes or 0
  numAsterisks = numAsterisks or 4
  local output = ""
  
  local numCharacters = numHashes + numAsterisks + numHashes * numAsterisks
  for i = 1, numCharacters do
    output = output .. (i % (numAsterisks + 1) == 0 and "#" or "*")
  end
  return output
end

-- test 
for i = 1, 5 do
  print(generatePattern(i, 6))
end
```