# Generating star pattern in LUA

Tags: lua

I am new to programming in LUA. And I am not able to solve this question below.

> Given a number `N`, **generate a star pattern** such that on the first line there are `N` stars and on the subsequent lines the number of stars decreases by 1.

> The pattern generated should have `N` rows. In every row, every fifth star (*) is replaced with a hash (#). Every row should have the required number of stars (*) and hash (#) symbols.

[Sample input and output, where the first line is the number of test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwAw9.png)

This is what I tried.. And I am not able to move further

```
function generatePattern()
  n = tonumber(io.read())
  i = n
  while(i >= 1)
  do
    j = 1
    while(j<=i)
    do
      if(j<=i)
      then 
          if(j%5 == 0)
          then 
             print("#");
          else
             print("*");
          end
        print(" ");
      end
      j = j+1;
    end
    print("\n");
    i = i-1;
  end
end

tc = tonumber(io.read())
for i=1,tc
do
   generatePattern()
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the ouput or the error? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I kind of got it, but all the stars are getting printed one after the other in a newline..Idk how to print in the same line to get the above said pattern

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259047/printing-the-required-number-of-inverted-star-patterns/64259674#64259674.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not follow this answer since it is bad coding style! I would delete it but SO won't let me. See comment and other answers for better solutions.

---

My Lua print adds newlines to each printout, therefore I concatenate each character in a string and print the concatenated string out afterwards.

```
function generatePattern()
  n = tonumber(io.read())
  i = n    
  while(i >= 1)
      do
        ouput = ""
        j = 1
        while(j<=i)
        do
              if(j%5 == 0)
              then 
                 ouput=ouput .. "#";
              else
                 ouput=ouput .. "*";
              end
          j = j+1;
        end
        print(ouput);
        i = i-1;
      end
end
```

Also this code is just yours minimal transformed to give the correct output. There are plenty of different ways to solve the task, some are faster or more intuitive than others.

Comment: Concatenating strings in a loop is considered bad style in Lua because of its terrible performance. Use `table.concat`, `string.rep` and `string.gsub` instead whenever possible. Also, avoid globals. They're bad.

Answer (score 2):

First, just the stars without hashes. This part is easy:

```lua
local function pattern(n)
  for i=n,1,-1 do
    print(string.rep("*", i))
  end
end
```

To replace each 5th asterisk with a hash, you can extend the expression with the following substitution:

```lua
local function pattern(n)
  for i=n,1,-1 do
    print((string.rep("*", i):gsub("(%*%*%*%*)%*", "%1#")))
  end
end
```

The asterisks in the pattern need to be escaped with a `%`, since `*` holds special meaning within Lua patterns.

Note that `string.gsub` returns 2 values, but they can be truncated to one value by adding an extra set of parentheses, leading to the somewhat awkward-looking form `print((..))`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on Lua version the metamethod __index holding `rep` for repeats...

```
--- Lua 5.3
n=10
asterisk='*'
print(asterisk:rep(n))
-- puts out: **********
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

for n = arg[1],  1,  -1 do
    local char = ''
    while #char < n do
        if #char %5 == 4 then char = char ..'#'
        else char = char ..'*'
        end  --  mod 5
    end  --  #char
    print( char )
end  --  arg[1]
```

chmod +x asterisk.lua
./asterisk.lua 15